# clusterMap from the parallel package - iterating over a number of parameters

Tags: r, parallel-processing, k-means

I am performing k-means on a large dataset (636,688 rows x 7 columns) and have therefore turned to parallelization. I would like to iterate over number of centers and have included an example in which I attempt to iterate over 2 to 5 centers 2 times each.

```
# Iris k-means parallelization example
library(parallel)
data(iris)
iris.cluster <- iris[,-5]

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
worker <- function(data, nclus, nstarts){
  kmeans(x = data, centers = nclus, nstart = nstarts)
}
myiter <- 2
nstarts <- rep(25, myiter)
nclus <- 2:5
results <- clusterMap(cl, worker, data = iris.cluster, nclus = nclus, nstarts = nstarts)
stopCluster(cl)
```

The summary already tells me something is amiss:

```
> summary(results)
             Length Class  Mode
Sepal.Length 9      kmeans list
Sepal.Width  9      kmeans list
Petal.Length 9      kmeans list
Petal.Width  9      kmeans list
```

`results` should actually have 8 rows and no descriptions to the left of `Length`. It appears as if I am only using one variable per list entry. I am unfortunately not entirely clear on `clusterMap` and whether it is the right way to go in this case. I now know how to iterate over seed and `nstart` values (thank you Steve Weston) but need help in order to iterate over number of clusters, as described above.

Comment: First, you shouldn't iterate over iris.cluster, so the data argument needs to be specified differently. Second, it looks like you have a two dimensional problem now, but you're specifying it incorrectly. It might be helpful to work out the sequential version of the code first.

Comment: If I try taking out `iris.cluster` from `clusterMap` - as it is already defined - like so:  `cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
worker <- function(nclus, nstarts){
  kmeans(x = iris.cluster, centers = nclus, nstart = nstarts)
}
myiter <- 2
nstarts <- rep(25, myiter)
nclus <- 2:5
results <- clusterMap(cl, worker, nclus = nclus, nstarts = nstarts)
stopCluster(cl)`, I get the following error: `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 4 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'iris.cluster' not found`. Thanks!

Comment: The worker function needs "iris.cluster", but you should not pass it as an iteration variable, otherwise it gets split up. Either export it to the workers via clusterExport, or pass it using the clusterMap MoreArgs argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're having a problem passing the arguments to the worker function properly. I believe you need a nested loop over "centers" and "nstart", and you should also export "iris.cluster" to the cluster workers since you don't want to iterate over it. Perhaps this is closer to what you want to do:

```
library(parallel)
data(iris)
iris.cluster <- iris[,-5]

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
clusterExport(cl, 'iris.cluster')
worker <- function(centers, nstart) {
  kmeans(iris.cluster, centers=centers, nstart=nstart)
}
myiter <- 2
nstarts <- rep(25, myiter)
nclus <- 2:5
g <- expand.grid(nstarts=nstarts, nclus=nclus)
results <- clusterMap(cl, worker, centers=g$nclus, nstart=g$nstarts)
stopCluster(cl)
```

This uses the "expand.grid" function to generate the arguments for a total of `length(nstarts) * length(nclus)` tasks.