# Convert R Script into a Single R Function

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions

I want to rewrite this `R code` as a single function. Here is the original `R code`

```
FUN <- function(i) {
  set.seed(i)
  ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model = list(ar = 0.7, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
  ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic = "aicc")
  (cf <- ar2$coef)
  if (length(cf) == 0) {
    rep(NA, 2)
  }
  else if (all(grepl(c("ar1|intercept"), names(cf))) &
           substr(cf["ar1"], 1, 3) %in% "0.7") {
    c(cf, seed = I)
  }
  else {
    rep(NA, 2)
  }
}

seedv <- 1:1e2

library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1 + 1)
clusterExport(cl, c("FUN"), envir = environment())
clusterEvalQ(cl, suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(forecast)))

res <- parLapply(cl, seedv, "FUN")

(res1 <- res[!sapply(res, anyNA)])

stopCluster(cl)

library(tibble)
res2 <- tibble(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))))

res2[order(res2$seed), ]

res2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x))))
res2[order(res2$seed), ]
```

Here is my result

```
#        ar1 seed
#1 0.7468994   51
```

Here is what I tried

```
FUN1 <- function(i, n, ar, arr, R, FUN2) {
  FUN2 <- function(i, n, ar, arr) {
    set.seed(i)
    ar1 <- arima.sim(n, model = list(ar=ar, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd)
    ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic = "aicc")
    (cf <- ar2$coef)
    if (length(cf) == 0) {
      rep(NA, 2)
    }
    else if (all(grepl(c("ar1|intercept"), names(cf))) &
             substr(cf["ar1"], 1, 3) %in% "arr") {
      c(cf, seed = I)
    }
    else {
      rep(NA, 2)
    }
  }

  seedv <- 1:R

  library(parallel)
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1 + 1)
  clusterExport(cl, c("FUN2"), envir = environment())
  clusterEvalQ(cl, suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(forecast)))

  res <- parLapply(cl, seedv, "FUN2")

  (res1 <- res[!sapply(res, anyNA)])

  stopCluster(cl)

  library(tibble)
  res2 <- tibble(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))))

  res2[order(res2$seed), ]

  res2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = T), lapply(res1, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x))))
  res2[order(res2$seed), ]
}
FUN1(i, n=10, ar=0.7, arr=0.7, R=100, FUN2=FUN2)
```

Here is the `error message`

```
#Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
#3 nodes produced errors; first error: argument "ar" is missing, with no default
```

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have changed the `FUN` to `FUN1`

Comment: I have tried to do something different on it but all result in error

Comment: `i` is a set of seeds that is called to use as `seedv`

Comment: You are not wrong

Comment: It may be better to have a look inside the `FUN2` function.  Also, probably you need `clusterMap`

Comment: If you check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705435/clustermap-from-the-parallel-package-iterating-over-a-number-of-parameters) the code works.  So, I am thinking that there is some issue in the `FUN2` function

Comment: maybe there are some issues about it

Comment: When I checked the `coef` on seed 1, `> coef(ar2)
numeric(0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237854/discussion-between-daniel-james-and-akrun).